# dsl connection failure

Tags: 14.04, internet, adsl

OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I had a working broadband connection. After repeated power failures, there was no internet connection.

After complaining, they restored the connection. The modem is showing that everything is connected. Only 'status' was connecting intermittently and gets disconnected.

ping worked fine. Then when checked with firefox and chrome, no pages were displayed. Chrome gave the message 'no internet'.

When I tried to set up using pppoeconfig, after giving the userid, password there is no further connection. ping also doesn't work.

The same problem with win 7 where the msg is not connected.

Would appreciate help to resolve the problem.

Comment: So, it's not a Ubuntu only related problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. The ISP had given the login id in lower case and the actual login was in upper case. This was the reason for the failure to connect to net.
2. The modem was also reset due which it could not be setup properly.

These led to the problem.

The problem was solved by resetting the modem with proper parameters.